# How do I dual boot Ubuntu 11.10 and Windows 7 with EFI?

Tags: grub2, uefi

I have a Lenovo ThinkPad x120e I just got, it came with Windows 7, I formatted it, installed a fresh copy (I just don't trust pre-packaged versions!) and in the process left some free space for an Ubuntu installation.

I grabbed Ubuntu 11.10, made a bootable USB drive, loaded up the live environment and ran through the install without a hitch, but rebooted and... straight to Windows.

My partition table looks something like this:

- 1.5 GB Root Partition (came with this--I assume it's "the EFI partition?") - NTFS (I think, if not, FAT32)
- 200 GB Windows 7 partition (NTFS)
- 80 GB ext4 partition with Ubuntu
- 2 GB swap
- 4(?) GB Recovery Partition (NTFS)

All I've found on here and in help sites are guides for 11.04 that involve manually compiling a bunch of things. How do I install grub2 on the EFI partition so I get a Windows 7/Ubuntu choice at boot?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I change/convert a  Ubuntu MBR drive to a GPT, and make Ubuntu boot from EFI?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/84501/how-can-i-change-convert-a-ubuntu-mbr-drive-to-a-gpt-and-make-ubuntu-boot-from)

Comment: "Now my question is, How can I change/convert Ubuntu's drive so that instead of using MBR it uses GPT and allow Windows to boot?." --seems like their situation is very different, what with it having two drives

Comment: Anna, I don't know enough about your situation to answer, intelligently, but here is the link I use to research how to do things with gpt and EFI: http://www.rodsbooks.com/gdisk/index.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried this some time ago on my Lenovo S205 and it still works just fine. The idea is to make it simple and actually work.

It uses windows loader for both OSs, and while it leaves you short of some Ubuntu maintenance options it works all right and allows updates etc.

Please make sure to use:

```
mount --bind /sys ./sys
```

and not

```
mount –bind /sys ./sys
```

otherwise follow the instructions sequence verbatim.
Here is the link
http://helms-deep.cable.nu/~rwh/blog/?p=177