# Change MBR to GPT on external hard drive with data

Tags: hard-drive, gparted, format, mbr, gpt

Change MBR to GPT on external hard drive with data:

I found a way for the internal one [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/84501/how-can-i-change-convert-a-ubuntu-mbr-drive-to-a-gpt-and-make-ubuntu-boot-from). However the External drive is a Data drive only, I dont't need to care about any bootloaders etc. So is there an easy way to do it?
It is a 3TB external drive, the setup in Gpartet looks like that:

| 8MB unallocated space|1,36TB ntfs with ca 300GB of data|1,36 of unallocated space|

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> *Note:* Like all operations involving partition manipulation, the below procedure carries some risk, and you are strongly advised to backup any critical data beforehand.

If this is a data drive only, I believe the start/end margins are sufficient, and a simple `sudo gdisk /dev/sdX` (follow steps) should do the job, converting the MBR to a GPT.

Comment: when I type it in it gives me Partition table scan:
  MBR: MBR only
  BSD: not present
  APM: not present
  GPT: not present


***************************************************************
Found invalid GPT and valid MBR; converting MBR to GPT format.
THIS OPERATION IS POTENTIALLY DESTRUCTIVE! Exit by typing 'q' if
you don't want to convert your MBR partitions to GPT format!
***************************************************************
Command (? for help): do I have to pu a "w" here?

Comment: Please verify the partition layout stays the same with `p`, and then write it with `w` -- that should do it...