# Cannot resize drive

Tags: gparted, partitioning

Here is my saved gparted log: http://pastebin.com/DDd0qH4N.

This seems to be the important part of the log:

> partition length of 5860530176 sectors exceeds the
>   msdos-partition-table-imposed maximum of 4294967295

Here is a screenshot of the unmounted drive:

[image: http://screencloud.net/v/7H3H]

Comment: What is the partition type used?

Comment: @Mitch Seems consistent with MBR limitations. Check my answer below.

Comment: @Braiam I know that, just trying to verify it with the OP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might have to boot into a Live CD/USB and do it from there.

In a Live CD/USB session, go to gparted and choose the drive you want to edit. It will give you a warning about potentially losing information (which can happen). If you choose to go ahead, it will take some time to resize, depending on the size of the drive.

The procedure is pretty straight forward. Gparted kinda walks you though it.

Answer (score 1):

> partition length of 5860530176 sectors exceeds the msdos-partition-table-imposed maximum of 4294967295

You are using the MBR which has an intrinsic maximum of *4294967295*. [Wikipedia source](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Master_boot_record#Partition_table_entries):

> Since block addresses and sizes are stored in the partition table of an MBR using 32 bits, the maximum size as well as the highest start address of a partition using drives that have 512-byte sectors (actual or emulated) cannot exceed 2 TiB−512 bytes (2,199,023,255,040 bytes or 4,294,967,295 (232−1) sectors × 512 (29) bytes per sector). Alleviating this capacity limitation was one of the prime motivations for the development of the GPT.

Hence you must switch to GTP or other kind of a partition table. You can check this [question in AskUbuntu](https://askubuntu.com/q/84501/169736) for a *"short"* how-to convert your MBR to GTP.

Answer (score 1):

I agree with Braiam, with his answer.  I also agree that you need to convert from MBR to GPT, and I have seen a lot of sites that will show you how to convert.  Some of the sites will go as far as saying that the conversion can be done without data loss.

Below is a small description of both an MBR, and GPT:

**MBR** is the standard partitioning scheme that's been used on hard disks since the PC first came out. It supports 4 primary partitions per hard drive, and a maximum partition size of 2TB.

**GPT** disks are new.  The GPT disk itself can support a volume up to 2^64 blocks in length. (For 512-byte blocks, this is 9.44 ZB - zettabytes. 1 ZB is 1 billion terabytes). It can also support theoretically unlimited partitions.

I personally like to be on the safe side.  I recommend that you get an up-to-date backup of your existing data, just in case.  I have seen this site come up a lot while searching on how to convert, and seen a lot of people recommend it.  See [Converting to or from GPT](http://www.rodsbooks.com/gdisk/mbr2gpt.html#gpt2mbr)

Comment: The drive is empty.