# Ubuntu taking too much time to boot

Tags: dual-boot, wubi

When I check the processes while booting using this command:

```
dmesg > ~/dmesg.txt
```

it shows delay here:

```
[   46.534002] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): wlan0: link becomes ready
[  895.868866] audit_printk_skb: 126 callbacks suppressed
```

Is there any solution ?

Comment: Are you intending to use IPV6?  If not maybe "ignore" it and see what happens.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `UEFI boot`/`coreboot` if your computer supports after first moving your installation outside a `wubi` container. To do this, create three new partitions on your HDD(make sure your `wubi` installation will fit into those partitions). I have reduced my boot time from `40` secs to `18` secs.

### First step(do this on a live CD)

-Issue `sudo dd if=<path-to-your-wubi-rootfs-imagefile> of=/dev/sda3 bs=512` from a Ubuntu or another Linux live cd in a terminal. Moving installation in this manner works, I had made a similar VM-to-real PC transistion. Do not copy swap partition, recreate it instead. Separate your home directory into a `ext4` partition by using your favorite partition editor(GParted is available on Ubuntu Live) and a file manager(move files from your `rootfs`'s `/home` directory to newly created partition-nautilus or `mv <path1>/home/* <path2>/` will help in such a case). You can share Documents directory among Windows and Linux.(this unfortunately does not apply to home directories). After moving rootfs and creating the other partitions, now you can install GRUB2 by `grub-install --boot-directory=<rootfs-partition-mount-point>/boot /dev/sda`.

### Second step(do this on your new destination)

Do a UEFI conversion according to steps described here: [How can I change/convert a  Ubuntu MBR drive to a GPT, and make Ubuntu boot from EFI?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/84501/how-can-i-change-convert-a-ubuntu-mbr-drive-to-a-gpt-and-make-ubuntu-boot-from) Be careful about not losing ability to boot `Microsoft Windows`. Try disabling IPv6 **after** moving your installation outside WUBI. WUBI is the primary cause of slowdown here.

Answer (score 1):

You can disable IPv6 if you don't need it. There are a few configurations, where IPv6 can significantly slow down startup time.

As root user or preprend with sudo:

- `echo 1 > /proc/sys/net/ipv6/conf/all/disable_ipv6`
- `echo "net.ipv6.conf.all.disable_ipv6 = 1" > /etc/sysctl.d/01-disable-ipv6.conf`
- `echo "net.ipv6.conf.default.disable_ipv6 = 1" >> /etc/sysctl.d/01-disable-ipv6.conf`
- `echo "net.ipv6.conf.lo.disable_ipv6 = 1" >> /etc/sysctl.d/01-disable-ipv6.conf`
- `sysctl -p`

Then reboot and tell us if it worked. Did fine for me. You can also blacklist the ipv6-module, but I'd recommend not doing so because other modules might need it to function properly.

Comment: Using `sudo echo` won't work. Try piping to `sudo tee` instead.

Comment: Thanks @bcbc, so true. But I wonder if that fixes the OPs problem, though.

Comment: It disable the IPV6 but my delay time is still there; Now the response of dmegs is:
[  582.250861] audit_printk_skb: 126 callbacks suppressed
[  582.250867] type=1400 audit(1413040085.769:75): apparmor="DENIED" operation="open" profile="/usr/lib/telepathy/mission-control-5" name="/usr/share/gvfs/remote-volume-monitors/" pid=2302 comm="mission-control" requested_mask="r" denied_mask="r" fsuid=1000 ouid=0

Comment: Try the steps in my answer, ie. move the installation outside WUBI. WUBI uses a loop device, and you see the block overhead three times every time you access disk.