# Ubuntu 15.04 takking to long to start on boot

Tags: boot, 15.10

There is a same question [Here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/525322/ubuntu-taking-too-much-time-to-boot#), But I think my problem is different so kindly provide me the solution if any one knows.

After performing this command:

```
#dmesg > ~/logs.txt
```

I found a delay here and it seems like my problem is with ACPI:

```
[   36.864428] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): wlan0: link becomes ready
[ 1533.228060] ACPI Warning: \_SB_.PCI0.PEG0.PEGP._DSM: Argument #4 type mismatch - Found [Buffer], ACPI requires [Package] (20150619/nsarguments-95)
```

Comment: This is a known bug https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/acpi/+bug/1383605

Comment: ohh it seems like lots of user have the same problem, okay so currently there is no solution with this ACPI booting problem? @TungTran