# GRUB not showing Windows 8.1 and Ubuntu 14.04.2 after Ubuntu 14.10 installation

Tags: 14.04, boot, dual-boot, grub2, 14.10

I have `Windows 8.1`, `Ubuntu 14.04.2` and `Ubuntu 14.10` on my machine. After installing the last, the `GRUB` is not showing the first two Operation Systems. I have try to fix this using `Boot Repair` but the `Recommended Repair` option did not fix the issue.

I have generated a `Boot-info Summary` since using advanced options of `Boot Repair` without understanding them could cause more problems.

Here is the [full report](http://paste.ubuntu.com/10849261/) and here is the initial part of it:

[image]

---

[image]

Comment: do you have both primary and logical partitions on this disk?  If so, I think the most likely culprit is that grub hasn't been installed to "/sda" (no number or anything after that....this ensures that grub is installed to the MBR of the primary disk on the system)

Comment: @user175999 Could you tell what should I do?

Comment: I would convert the disks to GPT if your hardware can accommodate it. This way you can get rid of your extended partitions and have all primary partitions which will aid both windows and grub in finding all of your different operating systems that are installed.

Comment: If you want to keep your current partition structure, I need to know how many total disks are in the machine.  #2 I need to make sure you at least have a bootable Ubuntu install disk or USB stick

Comment: I have one hard disk drive (2 TB) and I have `Ubuntu` on USB stick  - I am currently working using it (`Try Ubuntu` option) - do you mean this http://askubuntu.com/questions/84501/how-can-i-change-convert-a-ubuntu-mbr-drive-to-a-gpt-and-make-ubuntu-boot-from

Comment: Although that post has some relevant information, It is not crucial to solving your current problem. I believe once you have opened a sudo terminal.  (open terminal then type sudo -i) Then you can type grub-install /dev/sdX . (Just make sure you replace the "X" with a lowercase letter that corresponds to your 2 tb disk...the easiest way to do this is to launch gparted first to make sure "sda" as I suspect it is, is your 2tb disk.  Let me know if it looks like it helped at all)

Comment: Thanks, the `gparted` confirms it is `dev/sda`. So, I need simple to perform `grub-install /dev/sda`?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/22979/discussion-between-user175999-and-gotqn).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you have a way to access at least one Ubuntu installation, the answer goes as follows:
1. log in using Ubuntu intallation 
2. sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get dist-upgrade 
3. grub-install 
4. update-grub

Comment: (all commands need sudo first...easier way to input sudo password only once is... sudo -i (then enter sudo password and you don't have to type sudo every line))

Comment: sudo grub-install ; 
Installing for i386-pc platform. ; 
grub-install: error: install device isn't specified.