# Ubuntu Grub installation has error on Lenovo G50

Tags: boot, grub2, uefi

My laptop is **Lenovo G50** with x64 processor. But I cannot install ubuntu 64bit(Tried 16.04, 18.04, 20.04) on this. Currently I Have ubuntu 18.04 32bit. But the 64bit iso installer gives error in grub installation step.

The Grub installation error is:

```
The 'grub-efi-amd64-signed' package failed to install into /target/. Without the GRUB boot loader, the installed system will not boot.

Installer crashed

We,re sorry the installer crashed. After you close this window, we'll allow you to file a bug report using the integrated bug reporting tool. This will gather information about your system and your installation process. The details will be sent to our bug tracker and a developer will attend to the problem as soon as possible.
```

I booted in **UEFI** mode.

Also i created **EFI system partition**.

My Partition table is **MBR**.

What i have to do?

If i boot in the **legacy mode**, will be this sovled?

I'm **not** dual booting with other OS.

I'm not sure i set **EFI system partition** as **Primary**(Maybe i set this as **Logical**). Is this related?

Is anyway to use other **Bootloader**? Is this problem Only related to **Grub**?

Comment: If you're replacing the Ubuntu completely, Let the installer decide how to make partitions. It's very helpful to enable LVM partitioning, so you can easily change it later.

Comment: Thanks Danial. Yes. but i dont't want to lose my hard disk data. I think I should use GPT partition table instead of MBR. But my problem is that this requires to fully delete current data. and backuping all of hard disk is hard. Is there any way to change partition table from MBR to GPT without deleting current data?

Comment: Check out [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/824256/590937) if you want to convert from MBR to GPT, it will usually work without dataloss, but best to have  backups of data you don't want to lose under any circumstances.