# Convert ubuntu 18.04 MBR to UEFI boot

Tags: uefi, 18.04, mbr, secure-boot

have my ubuntu 18.04 booting in MBR mode. How can I convert it to boot UEFI with Secure Boot without having to reinstall it?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I change/convert a Ubuntu MBR drive to a GPT, and make Ubuntu boot from EFI?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/84501/how-can-i-change-convert-a-ubuntu-mbr-drive-to-a-gpt-and-make-ubuntu-boot-from)

Comment: @Smeterlink Did you have any luck with that link? thx

Comment: @WillZ couldn't test it yet.

Comment: I used Windows 10's mbr2gpt.exe tool to change my partitions from MBR to GPT. It worked after that. Note that I had do delete my linux partitions first before running mbr2gpt.exe because / partition is on the same hard disk as windows.