# Merging unallocated spaces as a single unallocated space to install windows

Tags: dual-boot, grub2, partitioning, system-installation, gparted

I'm trying to install windows 10 again(virus issues) along with ubuntu 18.04. Using windows 10 iso usb drive I've cleared the windows partition but I don't know why Gparted is unable to merge these 2 unallocated space as a single un allocated space.
[image: see this]

While installing windows I'm also getting the problem that my partitions are MBR and windows only allow GPT partitions so I'm unable to install windows 10 too.

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/questions/84501/how-can-i-change-convert-a-ubuntu-mbr-drive-to-a-gpt-and-make-ubuntu-boot-from provides an answer to the MBR>GPT issue

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu! If an answer solved your issue, click the checkmark next to it to mark your question as solved. It's not necessary to add [solved] to the title :)

Comment: If you found a solution to your problem and it is not contained in an answer here, it is perfectly fine to answer your own question. But please don't link those video tutorials.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is because the two spaces are not contigious on the drive and hence you cannot merge them. To work around this do the following steps:

- Boot from a Ubuntu LiveUSB and open gparted
- Extend /dev/sda1 (might be named differently) into one of the unallocated spaces
- Perform operations
- Now resize /dev/sda1 such that the now unallocated space is in the same side as the already existing unallocated space.
- Perform operations

Answer (score 3):

You'll have to add the space to `/dev/sda1` (the Extended partition) before adding the space to an adjacent partion contained within the `/dev/sda1` Extended partition.

Answer (score 1):

To collect the free space together you need to.

1. Boot off a livecd (you can't do this from within your main ubuntu install because it will involve moving your ubuntu partition)
2. Launch gparted.
3. Move the start or end of the extended partition.
4. Move the partitions inside the extended partition.
5. Move the other end of the extended partition.
6. Hit the go button
7. Wait a while for the data to be moved.

Comment: Would the downvoter care to explain what they think is wrong in this answer?

Comment: This worked, don't know why someone downvoted your answer.

Answer (score 0):

That's impossible because the unallocated spaces are physically before and after the partition in the middle.

Comment: now what should I do mate??