# Free space selecting problem

Tags: partitioning, system-installation, mbr

When I select free space, I can't click on `+` or change or anything and can't create anything. I have created my free space from tutorials.

```
$ lsblk
NAME MAJ:MIN RM SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT 
loop0 7:0 0 1,8G 1 loop /rofs 
loop1 7:1 0 86,9M 1 loop /snap/core/4917 
loop2 7:2 0 34,7M 1 loop /snap/gtk-common-themes/319 
loop3 7:3 0 140,9M 1 loop /snap/gnome-3-26-1604/70 
loop4 7:4 0 2,3M 1 loop /snap/gnome-calculator/180 
loop5 7:5 0 13M 1 loop /snap/gnome-characters/103 
loop6 7:6 0 14,5M 1 loop /snap/gnome-logs/37 
loop7 7:7 0 3,7M 1 loop /snap/gnome-system-monitor/51 
sda 8:0 0 298,1G 0 disk 
├─sda1 8:1 0 350M 0 part 
├─sda2 8:2 0 66,1G 0 part 
├─sda3 8:3 0 450M 0 part 
└─sda4 8:4 0 200,4G 0 part sdb 8:16 1 14,4G 0 disk 
└─sdb1 8:17 1 14,4G 0 part 
/cdrom sr0 11:0 1 1024M 0 rom



$ sudo fdisk -l /dev/sda 
Disk /dev/sda: 298,1 GiB, 320072933376 bytes, 625142448 sectors 
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes 
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes 
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: dos 
Disk identifier: 0x99fe47b4 
Device Boot Start End Sectors Size Id Type 
/dev/sda1 * 2048 718847 716800 350M 7 HPFS/NTFS/exFAT 
/dev/sda2 718848 139433983 138715136 66,1G 7 HPFS/NTFS/exFAT 
/dev/sda3 203890688 204812287 921600 450M 27 Hidden NTFS WinRE 
/dev/sda4 204812685 625140809 420328125 200,4G 7 HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
```

[image: Windows Disk Management screenshot]

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu.  I'm guessing you are talking about partitioning a disk, as you haven't given us much detailed information.  If your disk partition table is MBR/msdos, only 4 primary partitions (an extended counts as a primary) are allowed; so the system won't let you add a 5th one as the partition-table won't allow it. This is a guess as to your problem, as you haven't provided much information as to other alternatives..

Comment: I tried to add a photo but something goes wrong... Yes i have 4 nfts. I will try to upload picture here. What can i do?

Comment: Here is photo:
http://prntscr.com/l6nx46

Comment: Rather than posting a screenshot, please boot _Try Ubuntu without installing_, run the commands `lsblk` and `sudo fdisk -l /dev/sda` and paste the output to your question. (Or if you prefer to do it in Windows, follow https://www.howtogeek.com/245610/how-to-check-if-a-disk-uses-gpt-or-mbr-and-how-to-convert-between-the-two/.) Don’t forget to apply [code formatting](https://askubuntu.com/editing-help#code).

Comment: Is it correct now?

Comment: Yes, that’s exactly what I meant!

Answer (score 0):

According to the `fdisk` output, your partition table type is [MBR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Master_boot_record). (Called “dos” by `fdisk` as it was introduced in PC DOS.)

```
Disklabel type: dos
```

As [guiverc noted](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1084203/free-space-selecting-problem#comment1782661_1084203), you have exhausted the [limit of 4 partitions in the MBR](https://superuser.com/questions/370016/why-can-i-only-have-four-partitions).

**IMPORTANT NOTE:** Take a backup of the whole disk (e.g. using [Clonezilla](http://clonezilla.org/)) before doing any partition changes. It’s easy to do a mistake resulting in data loss when messing around with partitioning.

There are a few basic options on how to proceed:

- Move data from one of the existing partition to another, then remove it in Windows. It should be available for the Ubuntu installer then.

  1. To do so, boot Windows and move *all* files and folders (using Windows Explorer or Total Commander, for example) from the partition to be deleted, e.g. from the F: drive to D: drive.
  2. Then press <kbd>❖ Win</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> and open `diskmgmt.msc`. Select the partition to be deleted and run [`Delete Volume…`](https://www.computerhope.com/issues/ch001765.htm) from the context menu.
- If there is no regular partition to remove, you can also get rid of the [Recovery partition](https://www.lifewire.com/delete-windows-recovery-partition-4128723) or [System Reserved partition](https://www.terabyteunlimited.com/kb/article.php?id=409).
- The most complicated option: After moving the data and removing the partition, you can create an extended partition (which has own MBR with another 4 records available) and put the original partition back as a logical one. Then you can install Ubuntu into the rest of the extended partition.
- Convert your MBR to GPT.

  - [in Windows](https://www.thewindowsclub.com/convert-mbr-to-gpt-disk) – preferable in your case
  - [in Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/84501/how-can-i-change-convert-a-ubuntu-mbr-drive-to-a-gpt-and-make-ubuntu-boot-from)

Comment: How can I move data and delete it after?

Comment: I understand that but what to delete. Only which should be delete id this (Disk 0 partition 3) but it can't be deleted i dont know why. Doesn't exist right click on that 
http://prntscr.com/l703hc

Comment: I pasted link of screenshot in my question because i am not allowed to post pictures yet. I will delete this comments when you see this

Comment: @Matlab OK, I included your screenshot to your question and updated my answer with options to get rid of the non-standard partitions. I’ve already followed the guide to get rid of the System Reserved partition before but really do make a backup before proceeding.