# 19.10: I am trying to install Kubuntu alongside windows and there is no option to dual boot

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, grub2, system-installation, kubuntu

I am setting up my PC again with a clean slate. My drive was wiped and I installed windows on half of it. Now I'm trying to install kubuntu alongside it (last time it was all Linux) and there is no option in the installer. I have tried the manual mode but it complains about having no EFI partition, so I add a efi partition and it complains about grub failing. I tried making a ext4 partition in the empty space in gparted and writing over it and it's complaining about EFI partitions again. Here's some screenshots:

Install options:
[image: Install options]
The message when I try it without an EFI partition:
[image: The message when I try it without an EFI partition]
The partition scheme from the image above:
[image: The partition scheme from the image above]

Comment: Not sure, but think EFI partition should be Fat 32.  Windows would probably start complaining if you just reformatted EFI.  Easiest way would be a reinstall of everything, but that might be difficult for you.  Have had one chance of installing Windows after Ubuntu with UEFI system and went well(no grub lost).  This if sda1 is EFI.

Comment: Reinstall of everything is fine, I have literally nothing important on this. What should I do?

Comment: I would make EFI as Fat 32 format, install Kubuntu and then Windows.  Might need grub install/update after Windows, but that usually easy.  EFI should be flagged boot.  Can do Windows first after EFI reformat.  Windows fast boot should be turned off after loading Windows first time.

Comment: Yeah I'm trying my best to create an EFI partition but gparted won't let me move it to the front of the partition table. Do I need to wipe the entire thing and start again? This is an SSD and I would rather not write too much to it. Edit: There is a small (607MB, NTFS) windows system reserved partition, is that EFI?

Comment: Starting to wonder if Windows was installed as UEFI, is Win 8 and after, default option.  SSDs are usually decent now, so a reinstall should not matter too much. Would use GParted on live USB and set up all partitions first for EFI, Ubuntu and Windows and install.

Comment: I just installed Kubuntu on half the disk and then tried to install Windows on the empty space and now it's complaining about it being a GPT disk and it not being able to install. How do I get around that? Also, if I were to set up the partitions, how would I do it? Thanks for all the help you've provided, I would have no idea what to even try without it.

Comment: Windows installs in UEFI mode only on gpt partitioned disks, so your error indicates you are trying to install in legacy mode on a gpt disk,  Sorry, I cannot suggest how to force Windows installer to boot in UEFI mode.  Alternatively, install both Ubuntu and Windows in legacy mode on a dos partitioned disk (but only if you cannot figure out a Windows UEFI boot).Both should be in the same mode.

Comment: Which Windows are you using?  This link or the ones related might help to change.  Win 7 usually likes legacy and can google installing Ubuntu in legacy also.  https://askubuntu.com/questions/84501/how-can-i-change-convert-a-ubuntu-mbr-drive-to-a-gpt-and-make-ubuntu-boot-from

Comment: Which release of Windows did you use?

Answer (score 0):

Continue at your own risk
The bootloader should be installed correctly

I'd buy a second drive instald of dual boot though