# Convert MBR to GPT on macbook

Tags: mac, gpt, mbr

There is a nice thread [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/84501/how-can-i-change-convert-a-ubuntu-mbr-drive-to-a-gpt-and-make-ubuntu-boot-from) describing how to convert from MBR to GPT partition scheme. Unfortunately it says not to use it on apple macs. I have one of these, how can I here convert from MBR to GPT?

Comment: You understand that "converting" will wipe all data on the drive, right?

Comment: It does not necessarily delete all data, see https://techsviewer.com/how-to-convert-mbr-to-gpt-disk-without-losing-data-and-windows-os/